# Python + BS Picking a specific word(location) form webpage table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello all…I want to pick a word on specific locaiton from a table on webpage. The source code is like:

```
table = '''
<TABLE class=form border=0 cellSpacing=1 cellPadding=2 width=500>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top colSpan=3><IMG class=ad src="/images/ad.gif" width=1     height=1></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TH vAlign=top width=22>Code:</TH>
<TD class=dash vAlign=top width=5 lign="left">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=dash vAlign=top width=30 align=left><B>BAN</B></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TH vAlign=top>Color:</TH>
<TD class=dash vAlign=top align=left>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=dash vAlign=top align=left>White</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>

'''
```

I want to pick the word of color here (it could be “White”, "red" or something else). What I tried is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(table)

for a in soup.find_all('table')[0].find_all('tr')[2:3]:
    print a.text
```

It gives:

```
Color:
 
White
```

It looks like 4 lines. I tried to add them into a list then remove the unwanted but unsuccessful.

What’s the best way to only pick the color in the table?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match all instances of `'white'` case independent ...

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(table)

res = []
for a in soup.find_all('table')[0].find_all('tr')[2:3]:
    if 'white' in a.text.lower():
        text = a.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').replace(':','').split()
        res.append(text)
```

slightly better implementation ...

```
# this will iterate through all 'table' and 'tr' tags within each 'table'
res = [tr.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').replace(':','').split() \
        for table in soup.findAll('table') for tr in table.findAll('tr') \
        if 'color' in tr.text.lower()]

print res
[['Color', 'White']]
```

to only return the colors themselves, do...

```
# Assuming the same format throughout the html
# if format is changing just add more logic
tr.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').replace(':','').split()[1]
...
print res
['White']
```

Comment: thanks. sorry but I misled you. there are more colors and I want to pick the color, instead of specific words (question edited)

Comment: @MarkK this should suit your problem

Comment: thanks! the 'split()' here plays a very important role. well done!